# How to Email the Current Screen of iOS App in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I've created a form kind of app form, Where a user feeds the data and it dynamically processes it and displays the output there itself.

Now I want to write a code on Button say *Send Mail* Clicking on it should launch the default mail app (**it would be better if it launches without closing my application**) and should attach the current screen either in **Png** or **pdf** format of my form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a UIImage of the current screen by doing:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

as far as composing the mail goes, look at MFMailComposeViewController.

Comment: You will also need to make sure you have `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`